# Grammarly keeps asking me to change "would like to" to "want to", is that necessary?

Tags: word-choice

When I say:

> I would like to bring up two more questions:

Or something like that above, Grammarly keeps telling me to change it into:

> I want to bring up two more questions:

Is that necessary? Isn't `would like to` more polite?

Comment: See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+would+like+to+bring%2CI+want+to+bring&year_start=1969&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing how ***want to*** has displaced ***would like to*** over the past half-century. But if you want to sound "old-fashioned" that's your *choice* - there's  no concept of "right", "wrong", or "necessary" here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers
 I would not call a Google,Ngram a "usage chart", that seems to me to suggest a greater degree of authority and reliability than a Google Ngram possess. Indeed I would advise against linking to one without a cautionary note on the problems in deriving usage advice from this source. See my answer in this thread.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: We must agree to disagree. I'm perfectly happy to cite that ***written usage chart*** and endorse what it clearly reflects, which accords with my personal experience of language change. All the evidence I've seen in half a century since getting my degree in English language, literature, and linguistics points in the same direction. Raw compute power and non-rule-based text analysis wipes the floor with "curated" datasets and "manual" analysis. And in this specific case obviously at least *some* people will just go along with whatever Grammarly suggests, so it's "self-fulfilling".

Comment: AGamePlayer - just a few decades ago it was [also quite common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+would+like+to+bring%2CI+should+like+to+bring%2CI+want+to+bring&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) to use the even more "formal, indirect" auxiliary verb format *I **should** like to...* in such contexts. But that choice has fallen out of favour even faster than ***would***.

Comment: Q's example is an offer, not a request. I believe my answer offers a reasonable explanation for why a language model would offer the usage indicated.

Comment: :@fertilizerspike: I don't think so. It's an "offer" if *I would like to **give** you something* - where a "request" is *I would like to **ask** you something*.

Answer (score 1):

Both of

> - I would like to bring up two more questions.
> - I want to bring up two more questions.

are grammatically valid. I would say that the "would like to" version is a bit more formal, perhaps even a touch pompous. But a fluent speaker might well use either form, and there is no need to change one to the other.

Tools such as Grammarly can be helpful, but in my view they are not yet of sufficient quality that one can safely rely on them without double checking. Such tools often insist on changes that are not needed, and may even be changes for the worse.

Google Ngrams, the sourcxe of the "usage chart" linked in the [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330333/grammarly-keeps-asking-me-to-change-would-like-to-to-want-to-is-that-necess#comment624618_330333) by  
FumbleFingers, can be vary useful. But one should understand its sources and the pitfalls of using it. It reports the occurrence of short phrases in published books and magazines digitized by Google. Note that there are several different sets of texts, or corpuses, that can be used, and in this case the result is significantly different depending on which corpus is used. Also Ngrams reports only what  appears in such published sources, not in spoken English. (I don't think it includes newspapers, either.) It also does not treat separately old texts reprinted or quoted in new books. This can confuse the dating. Still it does show that both forms are in use, and that the "want to" form is currently in more frequent use within the Google corpus.

Comment: These language models being used online are very effective at pulling out common usage and trained on a lot of data. Sometimes where they seem to misrepresent strictly proper grammar they could just be picking out the generally favored use cases. In some ways this can be more helpful to new learners because it might give them better idiomatic use cases.

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to" may be considered more polite. This phrasing is generally also preferred if you are asking for something. While eating dinner and asking for salt ("i would like some salt") it may be more effective, perhaps because well-socialized people enjoy giving others things they like. Saying "i want salt" may seem abrupt to people accustomed to hearing "i would like". Abrupt language belongs in a combat zone where there is no time for ornate, clever language.

If you are not asking for something, eg "i want to show you something" or "i want the rain to stop" it will probably seem correct to most English speakers. It's a little bit easier to parse and that may be why a computer program prefered it and suggested it to you. In casual speech a general rule is to say things more simply.

If you notice the contradiction between abrupt language being seen as hostile but simple language being generally better, welcome to American English!